# Translate @media print @page CSS to Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following CSS:

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: ledger landscape;
  }
}
```

How can I do that in Tailwind?  And where would I put it?  Ideally, it's only applied to a certain part of my React app (so not on the `<html>` tag)

Comment: Do you not have an input css file you can add it to? https://play.tailwindcss.com/rS7jZ0wYra?file=css. Or is the problem more that you only want to apply it to certain parts of the app? In which case I would look at injecting the CSS into inline `<style>` tags when applicable.

Comment: We're almost entirely on Tailwind in our React / Next.js app, so trying to see if there's a way to keep it that way.  It's also not clear how to do this with inline CSS styles.

Comment: @Garrett I came across your question while looking into this myself, and as far as I can tell Tailwind currently doesn't support a number of at-rules, including `@page`. I imagine that it's possible to roll a custom plugin for it, but that might take some experimentation. The solution that I'm currently using is inline CSS with `styled-components`' `css` prop, which supports inline at-rules. I imagine that `@emotion/css` would work as well, and there are probably some other CSS-in-JS packages out there that could do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Currently (June 2023/v3.3.2) this is **impossible** with Tailwind CSS since the `@page` can't accept selectors — its value is applied for the entire application.

As a utility-first CSS framework, Tailwind CSS entire model is based on selectors.

---

As a **proof of concept** to show why this isn't possible, we can try to replicate some examples available at [Using arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) doc page.

In Tailwind CSS it's currently not possible to use `@page` without rules, but since this at-rule has the possible rules `:left` (selects even pages) and `:right` (selects odd pages) [[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page#syntax)], we can aim for both these rules, creating the following classes:

```
print:[@page_:left]:[size:ledger_landscape]
print:[@page_:right]:[size:ledger_landscape]
```

… which will generate the following CSS: [[playground]](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lp9P676XK6)

```css
@media print {
  @page :left {
    .print\:\[\@page_\:left\]\:\[size\:ledger_landscape\] {
      size: ledger landscape;
    }
  }

  @page :right {
    .print\:\[\@page_\:right\]\:\[size\:ledger_landscape\] {
      size: ledger landscape;
    }
  }
}
```

This CSS is —unfortunately— invalid.